# apply useEffect on an async function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a functional component in React:

```
export default function (id) {
    const [isReady] = useConfig(); //Custom hook that while make sures everything is ok
    useEffect( () => {
        if(isReady) 
            renderBackend(id);
    });

    async function renderBackend(id) {
        const resp = await getBackendData(id);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I am passing some props to the Functional Component like this:

```
export default function (id, props) {
    const [isReady] = useConfig(); //Custom hook that while make sures everything is ok
    useEffect( () => {
        if(isReady) 
            renderBackend(id);
    });

    async function renderBackend(id) {
        const resp = await getBackendData(id, props); // Passing props to backend
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Here the props are dynamic based on user input and changes time on time. But my code here is only rendering for the first prop, not on subsequent props. I want to call the backend every time props get updated or being passed. I think we might use useEffect for this, but not totally sure. And I cannot replicate this is codeSandbox as the real code is very complex and have trimmed down to mere basics.

Comment: pass a dependency array `[id]` as the second arg to useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 useEffect( () => {
        if(isReady) 
            renderBackend(id);
 });
```

to

```
 useEffect( () => {
        if(isReady) 
            renderBackend(id);
 }, [id]);
```

so `useEffect` function runs every time `id` changes

Answer (score 0):

As you do not put useEffect dependency, it will be executed for every re-render (state changed, ...)

So to execute the code within the useEffect every props change, put it to the useEffect dependencies list.

```
useEffect( () => {
        if(isReady) 
            renderBackend(id);
    }, [id, props]);
```

best practice is destructure your props and put only the affected value in the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

When using `React.useEffect()` hook consider that you have to pass the dependencies to gain all you need from a `useEffect`. The code snippet is going to help you to understand this better.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('something happened here');
}, [one, two, three]);
```

every time that one of the items passed to `[one, two, three]` you can see `something happened here` in your browser developer tools console.
I also should mention that it is not good idea at all to pass complex nested objects or arrays as a dependency to the hook mentioned.